# Where were Allied soldiers in Switzerland typically kept?

Tags: world-war-two, switzerland, prisoners-of-war

I've been researching for a short story, but I've been having trouble working out the exact trajectory of POWs who escaped from German camps into Switzerland. I know many were put up in hotels for the duration, but apart from [this article in a local paper, which mentions a handful in passing](http://www.laliberte.ch/news/dossiers/histoire-vivante/ces-soldats-etrangers-bienvenus-en-suisse-310004), I can't find any concrete information on the particular hotels they might have been in, or even the cantons. Is there information available on this? I'll happily take resources in French or German if anyone finds those.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Wauwilermoos internment camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wauwilermoos_internment_camp) and the links therein seem to have some of what you are looking for (2 other, similar, camps are mentioned). Apparently, only officers were put up in hotels and not required to work. You may find [this site](http://swissinternees.tripod.com/) useful as it has internees' stories and another page on internment camps.

Comment: @LarsBosteen The trouble is that the Wauwilermoos camp, while a blight on our national history, seems to have been reserved for soldiers who tried to escape. The other camps mentioned are very interesting, but I can't find any other references to them and I'm not clear on whether they were strict internment camps or the more "normal" work camps (which is what I'm after; I'm trying to give the characters a sort of break after Germany!)